# jsp receive 2 attributes but not the third

Tags: jsp, servlets

I set 3 attributes in my servlet, but only 2 are received in my JSP.

Here is the servlet part :

```
        profClassesSelect = Dao_Manager.retieveProfClasses(profLogin);
        request.setAttribute("listClassesProf", profClassesSelect);
        System.out.println(request.getAttribute("listClassesProf"));

        allClassesSelect = Dao_Manager.retrieveAllClasses();
        request.setAttribute("listAllClasses", allClassesSelect);
        allMatieresSelect = Dao_Manager.retrieveAllMatieres();
        request.setAttribute("listAllMatieres", allMatieresSelect);
```

and in jsp :

```
                    <div id="classeActionDiv" >
                <label> choisissez une classe :</label>
        <label>liste</label>
        ${listAllClasses}
        ${listAllMatieres}
        ${listClassesProf}
        </div>
```

So, the "listAllClasses" and the "listAllMatieres" are correctly displayed but the "listClassesProf" is not. And its not received as it is not in the source code. But I know the value is correctly set in the attribute as the

```
 System.out.println(request.getAttribute("listClassesProf"));
```

display what I want.

furthermore, I copied the console result and pasted it in my jsp, and it is displayed. I really don't understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your servlet code use the statement like this,

```
    request.setAttribute("listClassesProf", String.valueOf(profClassesSelect));
```

Comment: note : profClassesSelect, allClassesSelect and allMatieresSelect are all String.

Comment: may be it's the layout of the <div> element effect, just display only ${profClassesSelect} and check

Comment: damn i feel so stupid... i had an element with same name and with style display:none ... so thanks BalaYesu to get me on the way! :D

Comment: oh, another question (stupid one)... how to mark as Resolved? ^^'